# How can I read Collection of objects with MessageBodyReader

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, xsd, jax-rs

I have XSD Schema with some type, lets name it A.

Then I try to write MessageBodyReader with XSD Schema validation - it works if I pass single object there. But how can I manage it to read collection of these types?

I use that reader later for input parameters of REST Services, I register it in javax.ws.rs.core.Application.

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class AReader implements MessageBodyReader < A >
{
private static final String XSD = "/a.xsd";

@Override
public boolean isReadable(Class < ? > type, Type genericType, Annotation[] arg2, MediaType mediaType)
{
    return MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE.equals(mediaType) && A.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
}

@Override
public AreadFrom(Class < A> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
        MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap < String, String > httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream)
        throws IOException, WebApplicationException
{

    try
    {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class);
        try
        {
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

            unmarshaller.setSchema(getSchema());

            try
            {
                return (A) unmarshaller.unmarshal(entityStream);
            }
            catch (JAXBException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        catch (SAXException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
    catch (JAXBException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

private Schema getSchema() throws SAXException
{
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(A.class.getResource(XSD));
    return schema;
}
```

Comment: I must validate object against xsd schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the thing. An XML document must have a root element, so you can't just send something like

```
<domain></domain>
<domain></domain>
```

You would need to wrap it in a another root element, something like

```
<domains>
    <domain></domain>
    <domain></domain>
</domains>
```

That being said, the xsd schema also needs to reflect the other root element. You can't just have a `<domain>` element defined and expect to validate against `<domains>`.

Once you have that in your xsd, something like

```
<xsd:element name="domains">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="domain" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="domain">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
            <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence> 
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

We can then just make a `Domains` wrapper class, along with the `Domain` class

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Domain {

    @XmlElement
    private int id;
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    // Getters and Setters
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Domains {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "domain")
    private List<Domain> domains;
    // Getter and Setters
}
```

We can then create the `MessageBodyReader` to accept either `Domains` or `Domain` type. Something like

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class DomainMessageBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader {
    private static final String XSD_PATH = "path/to/domains.xsd";

    @Context
    private Providers providers;
    private Schema schema;

    public DomainMessageBodyReader()  {
        try {
            initSchema();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DomainMessageBodyReader.class.getName())
                                         .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            throw new InternalServerErrorException();
        }
    }

    private void initSchema() throws Exception  {
        SchemaFactory factory 
                = SchemaFactory.newInstance(
                                     XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        schema = factory.newSchema(new File(XSD_PATH));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class type, Type type1, 
            Annotation[] antns, MediaType mt) {
        return type == Domain.class || type == Domains.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object readFrom(Class type, Type type1, Annotation[] antns, 
            MediaType mt, MultivaluedMap mm, InputStream in) 
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try {

            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Domains.class, 
                                                          Domain.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
            return unmarshaller.unmarshal(in);
        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
            throw new InternalServerErrorException();
        }
    }  
}
```

<sub>Notice the `Providers` I didn't use it, but you probably want to check for a context that already exists in the `Providers` before jumping to create a new one. If there is none, then you can create a new one.</sub>

So with this `MessageBodyReader`, whether your JAX-RS resource method accepts `Domains` (`<domains>`) or `Domain` (`<domain>`), it will go through this reader, and send it to the correct resource method.